# necessary conditions for these conditionals to be consistent with some joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be random variables taking discrete values in the set $\{0,1\}$. I'm trying to find necessary conditions such that the conditional distributions $$X\mid Y,\,Y\mid Z,\,Z\mid X$$ are consistent with some joint distribution.

Comment: Do you mean you want all three conditional distributions to be the same?  Or are you asking which sets of conditional distributions come from some joint distribution?

Comment: Oh I'm asking which sets of conditional distributions come from some joint distribution.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out that that's the only way the question makes sense just about at the moment when I saved my comment.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm thinking I can use the fact that the conditional distributions $Pr[X=i|Y=j]$ and $Pr[Y=j|X=i]$ are consistent with some joint probability distribution if and only if $\frac{ Pr[X=i|Y=j] }{ Pr[Y=j|X=i] }$ is a rank one matrix. @MichaelHardy